# Rails Partials Not Loading with jQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery to tell Rails to render a partial. This works fine in Firefox and Safari, but when I dust off my Windows machine to test in IE8 or IE9, nothing is rendered.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#content').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "my_karma", :locals => {:list_id =>"my"}) %>");
```

Is there something I need to modify to get IE8 or IE9 to render this stuff? No errors are being thrown by Rails or IE, it just simply is not showing up. The Rails log even shows the files getting rendered.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you need more information, just ask. I will provide whatever I can.

Comment: Does the rendered HTML of the `append` method look like you'd expect? Any "interesting"/unusual CSS involved?

Comment: +1 to Dave Newton's respond - most likely it's bad Javascript. What does the Developer Tools have in the Console output and does the source output look right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with using

```
<!-- -->
```

type comments in my js.erb file. I replaced them with // type comments and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the `respond_to` block as well as perhaps the initial call to this JS ERB?

My initial guess is perhaps the browser isn't using the correct `dataType` or there's a problem with the render itself (including full layout or something along those lines).